# No Modern Authentication prompt in Office 2013

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

I have enabled Modern Authentication on my tenant and it works for Outlook 2016 clients.

I had to apply the following to avoid further basic prompts:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3126599/outlook-prompts-for-password-when-modern-authentication-is-enabled

However, for 2013 clients (on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit) it doesn't work (meaning it keeps giving basic prompts). They are up-to-date and I have applied the 2 reg keys as stipulated in this article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-Modern-Authentication-for-Office-2013-on-Windows-devices-7dc1c01a-090f-4971-9677-f1b192d6c910

I have also verified the minimum versions at:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-Office-365-modern-authentication-with-Office-clients-776c0036-66fd-41cb-8928-5495c0f9168a

Is there anything else I can do/check?